# Enumerable Intersect and Any Expressions do not compile to SQL

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-sql, expression

I'm trying to create an extension method for IQueryable which gets a function returning a `IEnumerable<Int32>>` as an input parameter, which should be checked against another constant list of numbers. If at least one identical entry is contained in both lists it should return true, something like `listA.Intersect(listB).Any()`. This expression also has to compile well to SQL (latest EF core) (`Intersect()` and `Any()` themselves should do). So here is what I came up with (yet):

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> AuthorizedRecords<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<Int32>>> employeeIds)
{
    var ids = (new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }).AsEnumerable(); // <- replaced later
    
    var methodAny = typeof(Enumerable)
        .GetMethods()
        .Where(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Length == 1)
        .First()
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));

    var methodIntersect = typeof(Enumerable)
         .GetMethods()
         .Where(m => m.Name == "Intersect" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
         .First()
         .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));

    var lambdaParam = employeeIds.Parameters.Single();
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Call(
            methodAny,
            Expression.Call(
                methodIntersect,
                Expression.Constant(ids), 
                employeeIds.Body
            )
        ),
        lambdaParam
     );
     
     var predicate = (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)lambda;
     return query.Where(predicate);
}
```

This code compiles but I get a runtime error that *The LINQ expression <...very long expression...> cannot be translated to sql*. What's wrong with the expression?

---

**UPDATE**

The expression seems to be fine, instead the `Intersect()` method fails for some reason. I reduced the code to this minimal Linq query reproducing the error:

```cs
dbContext.Meetings
  .Where(e => e.AccessList
    .Select(x => x.Id)
    .Intersect((new List<int>() { 90, 91, 92 })
    .Any()
  );
```

Now I get a *System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. bei System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(Expression body, String name, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters)*

What could be the problem with the Intersect query?

Comment: You're pulling the `Any` and `Intersect` methods of `Enumerable` rather than `Queryable`. `Enumerable` is in-memory LINQ.

Comment: Changed it to Queryable and noticed from the documentation that the second param of ```Intersect<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>) ``` has to be ```IEnumerable<TSource>```, so I swapped them in the ```Expression.call(...)```. When calling it with ```dbContext.Meetings.AuthorizedRecords(e => e.AccessList.Select(x => x.Id).AsQueryable()``` I get a runtime error *Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'parameter')*. When using a const List instead of ```e => e.AccessList.Select(x ``` everything works fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you update your question with the latest code / error?

Comment: Please see my answer below, I have posted my working code sample there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short: I did not find any solution to get `Intersect()` to work. Instead I changed my Linq expression to get rid of Intersect. I will post the solution for my use case, maybe it is useful for someone later.

The idea is to use

```cs
Where(ListA.Any(x => ListB.Contains(x))
// instead of 
// Where(ListA.Intersect(ListB).Any()
```

Here it is:

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> AuthorizedRecords<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, IQueryable<int>>> employeeIds)
{
  var ids = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }); // <- changed later

  var methodAny = typeof(Queryable)
        .GetMethods()
        .First(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));

  Expression<Func<int, bool>> contains = x => ids.Contains(x);
  
  var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
    Expression.Call(
      methodAny,
      employeeIds.Body,
      contains
    ), 
    employeeIds.Parameters
  );
  
  return query.Where(lambda);
}
```